# Azure Cloud Service Project Not Compatible With Worker Role Project in new .csproj format

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-worker-roles, .net-4.7.2

We are attempting to upgrade our existing Azure Worker Role project to target .NET 4.7.2, and to re-target all dependent projects in our solution to .NET Standard 2.0 - this is an intermediate step as we work to eliminate the Worker Role project entirely and migrate to .NET Core 3.0 Worker Service hosted in Docker containers.

All project files (`.csproj`) in our solution have been converted to the "new" format and we've eliminated `packages.config` and all is well. Almost.

The one remaining hurdle we have is trying to build our Azure Cloud Service project (the `.ccproj` file that produces the packaged worker role files for Azure). Attempting to build the Cloud Service project results in an error at line 1653 of `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`:

> Project `foo` targets `net472`. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets `.NETFramework, Version=v4.0`.

We are pretty much stumped at this point. I've not found any references to this specific error that are related to the worker role project in the new `.csproj` format.

I tried leaving the Worker Role project in the "old" project file format and targeting it to .NET 4.7.2 and the Azure Cloud Service project builds just fine -- *except* that NuGet package references from the dependent .NET Standard projects in our solution are not properly resolved and the NuGet package DLLs are not propagated to the build output folder - from what I've read, that's because the "new" project format method of referencing NuGet packages is not compatible with the old `packages.config` format. I've had to resort to manually adding one NuGet package at a time to the Worker Role project as new missing dependencies turn up at runtime. Obviously not a good solution when we have close to 100 NuGet packages in use in our project.

Comment: Have you found a way to overcome difficulties?

Comment: I have not. We'll just bite the bullet and do a full conversion to .NET Core and .NET Standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found from the following: [Azure Cloud Service Classic with .NET Standard target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160949/azure-cloud-service-classic-with-net-standard-target?rq=1)

Adding the following line in the .ccproj file fixed it for me:

```
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```